# Minimum number of subgroup whose union is $ \mathbb z_4 \times \mathbb z_4$ .

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product

Consider the group $ \mathbb z_4 \times \mathbb z_4$ of order 16 under component wise addition modulo 4. if G is union of $n$ subgroup of order 4 then minimum value of n is

a) 7

b) 4

c) 5

d) 6

My attempt:

number of elements of order 4 is 12 .these elements should  be in subgroup, so minimum number of subgroup implies optimal way of putting these elements.but maximum number of element 4 in a group of order 4 is 2. hence we divide by 2 .and we get 6.

but i'm not satisfy with my answer and i feel something is   wrong . is this correct ? if not, please help !

Comment: You've proved $6$ is a lower bound. Now see whether you can find six subgroups that work.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: @GerryMyerson first if all thank you for remember me on your busy day ..i actually found 6 subgroup which has all elements of G . And also i complete my argument  .Thank a lot..

Comment: Let me encourage you to post your findings as an answer to your question.

Comment: Its 2 am here.... I will post it tomorrow...plz forgive me